# import module without executing whole script python

Tags: python, module

I have script like this

```
if int(isValidUser)==1:
            UserNameTB.place_forget()
            PasswordTB.place_forget()

            import MainPage

        else:
            tk.messagebox.showinfo(message="wrong account")
```

I have window called mainForm so when I run this code it opens windows where are LogIn form.
so for example someone Loged in correctly it imports MainPage (mainPage is account window)

the mainPage script is like this:

```
import LogInPage
import tkinter as tk
menubar=tk.Menu(mainForm)
menubar.add_command(label="Customer",command=ShowCustomerWidgets)
menubar.add_command(label="Operator",command=ShowOperatorWidgets)
menubar.add_command(label="Admin")
mainForm.config(menu=menubar)
```

So when It runs this script it creates another Window where is still LogIn form and also mainPage widgets, how could I stop this, so for example when user Logs in the window stayed the same but different widgets came up and old ones disappear.

P.S I can't put the whole code in One .py file

Comment: Looks like it's a `tkinter` question, not just `python`

Answer (score 0):

If the problem is arising from executing the `LogInPage` during the import... you can protect the code in LogInPage. Keep those codes in `if __name__ == '__main__:` block from being executed by import statements.